# How to join 2 strings together with delimiter?

Tags: php

I have a string like this `$value[0] = "8000297c - 1360598144 "`

I explode them into 2 pieces by doing this : `$elements = explode('-', $value[0]);`

Then I created 2 variables to store them :

```
$first = strtolower($elements[0]); // 8000297c 
$last  = strtoupper($elements[1]); // 1360598144
```

Now- after **formatting** them, I want to join them back to the original format like this

- `$first."-".$last`

I was thinking to use `implode()` function, and I tried

- `$polish_sku = implode("-", $first, $last);` - then, I got this :

[image]

I hope someone don't mind and point out what I did wrong. :D

Comment: If you [read the documentation!](http://php.net/implode) you can see that you have to use an array. `implode('-', array($first, $last))`.

Comment: If you have just 2 variables to connect, what is wrong with `.`?

Comment: Another method is assign both variables to one, then do `$polish_sku = implode("-", $newvar);`

Comment: You don't even need to explode them in the first place if all you want to do is convert both parts to upper case, simply use `$polish_sku = strtoupper($value[0]);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you want to use implode

```
implode("-", array($first, $last));
```

or just concat them ?

```
$first . "-" . $last
```

or use printf/sprintf ?

```
printf("%s-%s", $first, $last)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", $first, $last);
```

should be

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", array($first, $last));
```

Moreover you can simply take advantage of string concatenation like

```
$polish_sku = $first.'-'.$last
```

or

```
$polish_sku = sprintf("%s-%s", $first, $last);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", $elements);
```

if `$elements` has two or more elements:

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", array($elements[0],$elements[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", array($first, $last));
```

implode takes an array as the second parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
$polish_sku = implode("-", array($first, $last));
```

would work if you want to use implode

Comment: ok. let me try. thanks :D